# Thread suddenly stops with no exception or error message

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming

I got a thread that reads and writes to a network socket.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.1.11", 19456);
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String message = "13" + seperator + "0" + seperator + "userdata";
        out.write(message);
        out.flush();

        while (listen) {
            String input = "";

            for (int letter = in.read(); letter != -1; letter = in.read()) {
                System.out.println((char)letter);
                input += (char)letter;
            }

            System.out.println(input);
            displayText(input);
        }

        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        displayText("Could not connect to server!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        displayText("Could not open IO to server!");
    }
}
```

However, everything after the for-loop is not executed. The System.out.println inside the for-loop prints out all the letters it's supposed to, but the System.out.println and displayText function after the for-loop are never executed (checked with breakpoints)... What am I missing here? :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read

```
This method will block until a character is available,
an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.
```

Their code example does show they -1 is returned on EOF.

So, your for loop is blocking because **in.read()** is not recognizing the EOF condition.

And it can't do that until the socket server shuts down its send direction, which closes the receive half at the client.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start the program in the debugger
2. Reproduce the bug
3. Check whether the thread still exists (in eclipse, the debug view lists all processes, which their threads)

   - If the thread exists: suspend it (in eclipse, by clicking the thread and pressing the pause icon). The debugger will now show the stack for that thread, so you can inspect what it was doing.
   - If the thread doesn't exist anymore, it must have terminated normally or abruptly (due to an unhandled exception). You can distinguish this by setting a break point on the last statement in run(). If it completed abruptly, the thread's uncaught exception handler must have been invoked.